# Overridable method call in constructor - what is the proper way to call the method?

Tags: java

What is the difference between these two calls? How should this be done properly?

```
//package test;

public class SomeClass {

    public SomeClass() {

        doSomething();//Warning - Overridable method call in constructor
        SomeClass.this.doSomething();//Seems OK
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        //...
    }
}
```

I want to use `doSomething()` just for convenience in the same class. I have no intentions to override it later. One idea is to declare it `final`. But still it is not clear if `SomeClass.this.doSomething();` is safe to use in this situation.

Comment: The compiler warning notification somewhat says what can happen. If a subclass overrides the `doSomething` method, it can change the behavior when creating the class instance, which may be dangerous or not, depending on your design. Note that it's a warning, not a compiler exception.

Comment: do you want the method to be overridable? if yes, no, or  depends on by who? then use public, private, or protected/package scope for your doSomething() method

Comment: Concerning "How should this be done properly": If possible you could try to avoid something like this. Either do not call the method, or declare it as `final`. It's not always easily possible, but you should at least consider it.

Comment: vote to put on hold: unclear what you're asking. Please clarify what you mean by 'how should this be done properly?' by telling us whether or not you actually want the method to be overridable.

Comment: Yes, I have no intention to override it later, to make it `final` it's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler warning notification somewhat says what can happen. If a subclass overrides the doSomething method, it can change the behavior when creating the class instance, which may be dangerous or not, depending on your design. Note that it's a warning, not a compiler exception.

To prove this, just extended your code to test it:

```
class SomeClass {

    public SomeClass() {

        doSomething();//Warning - Overridable method call in constructor
        SomeClass.this.doSomething();//Seems OK, but is not
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass extends SomeClass {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("child");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass a = new SomeClass();
        SomeOtherClass b = new SomeOtherClass();
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
parent
parent
child
child
```

If you just want that no other class can override `doSomething` method, mark it as `final`:

```
class SomeClass {

    public SomeClass() {

        doSomething();//Warning - Overridable method call in constructor
        SomeClass.this.doSomething();//Seems OK
    }

    public final void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }
}
```

Then if any subclass tries to override it, the compiler will throw an error:

```
public class SomeOtherClass extends SomeClass {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() { //compiler error
        System.out.println("child");
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Very good example, thanks :) I got the idea now. Also -  `SomeClass.this.doSomething();` - I think in this situation would be OK - I think it is no difference if it later will be overridden - the method would be called from SomeClass as is. Am I right?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis no, since you call `this` it will call the current object instance and will execute the method that belongs to the current object type. Otherwise, the could would have printed *parent parent child parent*.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. :) Stupid me what can I say :) It was so simple.. Now the question is 100% answered. Thanks for help indeed.